# Ng-container not showing when clicking button

Tags: html, angular, typescript

This is my portion of html code:

```
    <div>
      <button
        type="button"
        class="add-emp-btn"
        *ngIf="!addEmployeeBtnClicked"
        (click)="onEmpBtnClicked()"
        [disabled]="newProjectForm.invalid"
      >
        Add Employees
      </button>
      <ng-container *ngIf="addEmployeeBtnClicked" formArrayName="employees">
        <div *ngFor="let employeesControl of getControls(); let i = index">
          <label for="userName">Insert one or multiple Users Names to submit</label>
          <input type="text" [formControlName]="i"/>
          <div class="width-divider"></div>
          <button type="button" class="goto-add-emp-btn">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
```

The button clicked logic works because if i put the *ngIf in the div where the *ngFor now is, the button is hidden and the other 3 elements are shown. But of course i need the *ngFor there, that's why i wrapped everything with ng-container. I did this already few lines of code above and worked in that case.
I must be missing something trivial.

Tl;dr: when Add Employees  button is clicked, it should disappear and the ng container with the lable, input text and Cancel button, should appear

Comment: i am reading the question 10th time in a row and still can't understand what do you want to achieve. could you provide the desired piece of html you are trying to get, or describe it better somehow

Comment: When the button Add Employees is clicked, it should be hidden. In that place the elements of the ng container should appear. Dont mind the css classes i have to fix those, i'm doing it only with ngIf.

Comment: You can try `[hide]="addEmployeeBtnClicked"` instead of *ngIf

Comment: What is the return value of getControls()

Comment: it s an empty array because it should allow to insert new users

Answer (score 0):

I copied this code, changed a few things because I don't have your surround code and it works.   Things to check:

- In the onEmpBtnClicked() method, are you setting addEmployeeBtnClicked to true?
- Have you done an F12 to check the developer console to see if there is some error preventing display?
- What is getControls() providing?  Is there data to display?

Comment: I didnt change a thing and today it works, i dont even know what to say